# iOS "search" key on keyboard does not do anything

Tags: html, ios, input, keyboard

I have an HTML website with a input field for users to do searches. However, after typing in a query on iOS or Android and hitting "Search" from the soft keyboard, nothing happens.

I'm having trouble finding discrepancies of mobile Safari and webkit. Any leads please? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Usually the Search key submits the HTML form. Are your input fields surrounded in a <form> tag?

Comment: Yeah, they are in a <form> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought i'd let anyone know the resolution:

I notice that hitting the "Return" button on my physical keyboard also did not work, so i added a Javascript listener to handle the keyup event 13. This leads to the last piece:

Make sure your input type = "search" (i had mine as "text"). Now you're ready to go!

```
$('search_field').observe('keyup',function(e){
            if(e.keyCode === 13){
                NAME.search($('search_field'));
            }
        });
```

Cheers